# Numpy Where передать строку как переменную

Tags: python, numpy, where

Ищу в Pandas DataFrame координаты ячейки содержащей нужный мне текст.
Для этого использую Numpy where.

```
rows, cols = np.where(df == 'Нужный мне текст')
```

Когда пытаюсь сравнивать с переменной содержащей текст, то ничего не находит:

```
text_to_find='Нужный мне текст'
rows, cols = np.where(df == text_to_find)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в Numpy Where искать текст, содержащийся в переменной.

Comment: Я попробовал, вообще-то работает одинаково. Что-то вы не то делаете. А текст вы на полное совпадение именно проверяете?

Comment: Действительно все работает, ошибка была у меня, в DataFrame были слова с буквой ё, а искал я без нее.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно документации `where` возвращает не `rows` и `cols` а `ndarray`

Создадим простой датафрейм

```
>>> d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> print(df)
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
```

А теперь попробуем найти 1 в нашем датафрейме.

```
>>> np.where(df == 1, df, -1)
```

Первым аргументом передаем условие, вторым сам датафрейм, а третьим то чем следует заполнить данные которые не будут совпадать с данным условием, например `-1`

Таким образом в качестве результата получаем массив:

```
array([[ 1, -1],
       [-1, -1]])
```

Если вместо `-1` будем использовать `0` получим:

```
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 0]])
```

Теперь как мы можем получить все таки колонку и строку — отбрасыванием

```
>>> df.where(df == 1).dropna(how='all')  # отбрасываем строки
```

А тут мы отбрасываем и строки и колонки

```
>>> res = df.where(df == 1).dropna(how='all').dropna(axis=1)
```

В итоге получается такой результат

```
   col1
0   1.0
```

Получить строку мы можем таким образом

```
>>> res.index 
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

Получить колонку таким образом

```
>>> res.columns 
Index(['col1'], dtype='object')
```

Но это может быть не совсем удобно, что если нам нужны tuples в виде (row, col)?

Тогда мы можем сгенерировать их массив таким образом:

```
[(df[col][df[col]==1].index[i], df.columns.get_loc(col)) 
  for col in df.columns 
    for i in range(len(df[col][df[col]==1].index))]

[(0, 0)] # массив туплов (row, col)
```

Вместо выражения `df[col]==1` можно использовать функциональный эквивалент `df[col].eq(1)` — дело вкуса.